# Using Variable in Node Attribute

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I am writing a XSL template. I am not getting how to specify a variable for a custom attribute inside XSL file.

I am trying this code in XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="DEF"/>    
<frequency myAttr="ABC"+$var1 >    
     <xsl:value-of select="frequency"/>    
</frequency>
```

Expected result is

```
<frequency myAttr="ABCDEF" >20</frequency>
```

I am getting this error:

> Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 24; Element type "sourceId" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

The issue is the way I am concatenating is wrong. Any help in achieving this?

Comment: The error message refers to there being an unterminated element named `sourceId` on line 18 of some file. You haven't shown us any element called `sourceId`, or any file with >18 lines, so clearly this error is unrelated to the code you have shown us. However, the code you have shown is wrong for other reasons, as @michael.hor357k explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean :

```
<frequency myAttr="ABC{$var1}" >
```

This will concatenate the literal string `"ABC"` with the content of the `$var1` variable - see: [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates).

Note that the way you populate the variable suggests there is an element named `DEF` in the source XML. The expected result will be obtained only if this element has a string value of `"DEF"`.

Answer (score 0):

XSL is a declarative language in XML format. An XSLT file must be well-formed XML.

What you tried looks like you have programming knowledge of an imperative language where you can write expressions like `"ABC" + $var1`. This violates the XML format rules in XSL however. Elements follow the pattern `<elementname attribute1="value1" attributeN="valueN">...</elementname>`. In your code, you put `+$var1` after the end of the myAttr attribute, which ends at the second quote mark - and this is invalid: `<frequency myAttr="ABC"+$var1 >`

`<frequency myAttr="ABC+$var1">` would result in a literal attribute value of `ABC+$var1`, which is not what you want. This would also happen if you tried to use XPath syntax as attribute value, `concat('ABC', $var1)` as string from `<frequency myAttr="concat('ABC', $var1)">`.

You can use the Attribute Value Template syntax as michael.hor257k suggested, which essentially means to wrap XPath expressions in curly braces inside of attribute value strings.

Another way would be to not write the element as literal in your code, but rather declare it:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="'DEF'"/>
<xsl:element name="frequency">
  <xsl:attribute name="myAttr">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('ABC', $var1)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Note that I corrected the variable definition: In the `select` attribute, you must put `DEF` in single quote marks if this is supposed to be a string, like `select="'DEF'"`. Without the single quote marks you define the variable to refer to `<DEF>` elements in the source XML.

In the `select` attribute of `<xsl:value-of>` I used the XPath function `concat()` to concatenate the string `'ABC'` and the content of the variable `$var1`. The attribute value template syntax can not be used here: `select="'ABC{$var1}'"` would result in the string `ABC{$var1}`.

A variation of above example would be to use `<xsl:text>` for the string `ABC` and `<xsl:value-of>` to output the content of `$var1`:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="'DEF'"/>
<xsl:element name="frequency">
  <xsl:attribute name="myAttr">
    <xsl:text>ABC</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

So there are three solutions, a concise one and two declarative ones. Which one you choose is up to you. The quickest to type is certainly the first:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="'DEF'"/>
<frequency myAttr="ABC{$var1}">
  <xsl:value-of select="frequency"/>    
</frequency>
```

... but you should also be aware of both declarative ways to achieve the same result and understand how they work.

Comment: Actually, there is a third option. I would certainly not use `concat()` when writing directly to the output - so if **not** using AVT, I would have used two separate instructions - `xsl:text` and  `xsl:value-of` -  inside the `xsl:attribute` element.

Comment: True, added it as variation of the declarative example. I prefer `concat()` because it is faster to extend IMO, but YMMV especially with the editor you use. I don't think that it really matters what you use in terms of performance.